# How do I connect local nodeJS server with MySQL which is running on AWS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-ec2, mysql-error-1064

Here is my code to connect with MYSQL, I am getting `connection timeout` error :

This is my connection file to connect with MYSQL :

```
/*
* @sqlConnection
* Creates the connection, makes the query and close it to avoid concurrency conflicts.
*/

var mysql = require('mysql');
var sqlConnection = function sqlConnection(sql, values, next) {

    // It means that the values hasnt been passed
    if (arguments.length === 2) {
        next = values;
        values = null;
    }
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        "host": process.env.dbHost,
        "user": process.env.dbUser,
        "password": process.env.dbPass,
        "database": process.env.dbName,
        "port":process.env.dbPort
    });
    connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err !== null) {
            console.log("[MYSQL] Error connecting to mysql:" + err + '\n');
        }
        else {
            console.log("Connection is available");
        }
    });

    connection.query(sql, values, function (err) {
        connection.end(); // close the connection

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        // Execute the callback
        next.apply(this, arguments);
    });
};

module.exports = sqlConnection;
```

This is the error what I am getting :

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (/home/himanshu/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:411:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:420:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
    --------------------
```

I think I am doing something wrong in the config file which looks like, I don't know what to provide in db HOST or How actually I can connect with aws mysql db :

```
dbHost=00.00.000.000 // aws instance ip
dbName=HIMANSHU
dbUser=ROOT
dbPass=PASSWORD
dbPort=3360
```

Answer (score 0):

@Himanshu Just check the Inbound rule of your Instance.
As per your code, it looks like you are running MySQL in your EC2 machine.

So just make sure, you have allowed 3306 port in your Inbound rules and outbound rules also

Comment: I just set the inbound rules and now I am getting ```Error connecting to mysql:Error: connect ECONNREFUSED``` error.

Comment: your DB port is 3360 in your conf file, if not changed manually then changed to 3306. make sure your inbound rule is set according to db port only.

Comment: just make sure on which port your db is listening